# Adding modal popup to cells in ant design table

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd, react-table, react-modal

I'm trying to add modals to a column in ant design table, so when I click on the value in a cell, a modal will popup. But I can't seem to make it work when I tried to add a onCell property. What should I write for the onClick function? I tried this.showModal; but it does not work.

Here is the code for setting properties for the column:

```
for (let i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
  columns.push({
    title: "2021" + (i + 1 + 5) + "F",
    dataIndex: "a" + (i + 2),
    align: "right",
    render: (text) => <a href="#">{text}</a>,
    onCell: (record, rowIndex) => {
      return {
        onClick: () => {
          //insert show modal function
        }
      };
    }
  });
}
```

Here is a working sandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/dynamic-settings-antd4167-forked-0kcu0

Answer (score 0):

Did you use `onCell` in `columns`? I tried and it worked

```
const tableColumns = columns.map((item) => ({
      ...item,
      ellipsis: state.ellipsis,
      onCell: (data, index) => {
        return {
          onClick: (event) => {
            console.log("click");
            this.showModal()
          }, // click row
        };
      }
    }));
```